# How to set the x axis of HighCharts to intake DateRange

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to display a series of data for a specific set of Dates, say for 15 or 30 Days. Now, I don't want to display all these dates on x-axis instead, because that will be too many and it will be difficult to understand, instead want to plot it on intervals so that y-axis data can fit correctly.
Below is how I was displaying everything which is looking clumsy and difficult to read

```
"xAxis": {
  categories: [
    '10 June',
    '12 June',
    '14 June',
    '16 June',
    '18 June',
    '20 June',
    '22 June'
 ]
 },
"series": [
  {
    name: 'Total Students',
    data: [1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 60]
  }
]
```

Is there a way to make the x-axis populate dynamically to display a large range of dates? Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'datetime'` axis type and set `x` and `y` data in this way:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},
series: [{
    name: 'Total Students',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2013, 8, 16), 0.7500],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 8, 17), 0.7486],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 8, 18), 0.7396],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 8, 19), 0.7391],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 8, 20), 0.7394],
    ]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xq52vagL/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type